# Will a Google Apps Script Library be loaded multiple times if it is included more than once?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a project where I use libraries to deal with DB models management.

If I have a **Customers_Library** library for Customers-related functions which needs my main **DB_Connection_Library**, and then I load in the same project the **Orders_Library** which also uses the latter as a dependency...

Is GAPS smart enough to know both 'child' libraries are loading the same 'parent' library? Or is it each loading an instance of it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When a library is loaded a new instance of the script is ran, but it will still use the same User and Script Property Store. For example:

Common Library -> Lib1 (has Getters/Setters for Common Lib Property Store)
Common Library -> Lib2 (has Getters/Setters for Common Lib Property Store)
Lib1 & Lib2 -> new Project

If new Project uses either Lib1 or Lib2 getters and setters for the common library each will run its own instance (unique 'this' object) but if you get or set from Common Library user property store it will be shared with all instances of Common Library.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit? I don't know what you mean when you refer to "Script Property Store". I have a JDBC helper in my common library. If Customers and Orders both use my Common library, each will have a separate instance of the JDBC object, am I right?

Comment: Every time you make a method call to your Common library a new instance of your JDBC object will be created.  There is no persistence between method calls.

Comment: So I guess that it would be a terrible practice to include several libraries each depending on the same common one in terms of application performance, wouldn't it? I should better separate the child libraries and do the loading at reverse order: project -> include common lib -> include all children libraries.